# nginx error 'Cannot match any routes' with Angular 2 router 3.0.0.-alpha.7

Tags: nginx, angular, router

nginx doesn't seem to work with prod builds of Angular 2 RC3's router.  I get the following error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: ''
at s (zone.js:538)
at zone.js:515
at t.invoke (zone.js:323)
at Object.onInvoke (ng_zone_impl.js:46)
at t.invoke (zone.js:322)
at t.run (zone.js:216)
at zone.js:571
at t.invokeTask (zone.js:356)
at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone_impl.js:37)
at t.invokeTask (zone.js:355)
```

My nginx configuration is very simple:

```
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;
    charset utf-8;
    location / {
        root   /Users/JARVIS/src/web/ui/dist;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

I can't tell if this is a problem with how it's configured or with the new router or with the way it's compiled.  I'm using the angular2-webpack-starter.  This issue only happens with the prod builds hosted in nginx.  In the development server everything works fine.

My routes are pretty straight forward:

```
export const ChromeRoutes: RouterConfig = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: Chrome,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard], // this protects all child routes
    children: [
      { path: 'dashboards', component: Dashboards },
      { path: 'inventory',  component: Inventory },
      { path: 'content',    component: Content },
      { path: 'settings',   component: Settings },
      { path: '',           redirectTo: '[/dashboards]' }
    ]
  }
```

I have tried changing '' to 'chrome' with no change.  With or without the redirectTo entry doesn't matter either.

---

Edit:
My full routes definition via a JSON.stringify()...
`javascript
[{
    "path": "login",
    "terminal": true
}, {
    "path": "",
    "canActivate": [null],
    "children": [{
        "path": "dashboards"
    }, {
        "path": "inventory"
    }, {
        "path": "content"
    }, {
        "path": "settings"
    }]
}, {
    "path": "inventory",
    "canActivate": [null],
    "children": [{
        "path": "",
        "terminal": true
    }, {
        "path": ":id"
    }]
}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you have `<base href=".">` in `<head>` try changing it to `<base href="/">`
- Add `terminal: true` the empty path route

```
{ path: '',           redirectTo: '[/dashboards]': pathMatch: 'full' }
```

**<= RC.3**

```
{ path: '',           redirectTo: '[/dashboards]': terminal: true }
```

Comment: terminal is deprecated; instead should be: pathMatch: 'full'

Comment: Thabks for pointing it out. Hard to keep up with all these changes ;-)

Comment: I made sure all paths (with exception of the root route) that have `path: ''` have `terminal: true`.  My base href is '/'.  Still get the same error.

Comment: I've edited to provide the end result of my whole route config combined.  See original question.

Comment: So, it appeared to be a combination.  I commented out all routes and worked through this.  The base href was part of the key.  Also look for APP_BASE_HREF being set.  Then ensuring that the children array had a `path: '', redirectTo: '/default', terminal: true` seemed to make it all work.